# How to load a discount rule by id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I try to take the discount ammount from a discount rule by id.
My discount rule it's  coupon code, and i got the id like this:

```
$ids = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

Does anyone know how to load this rule by his id?

Answer (score 2):

With Magento 2, you should always prefer using repositories to get data.

First you need to inject the `RuleRepositoryInterface` in your class' `__constructor`:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $ruleRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $ruleRepositoryInterface
 */
public function __construct (
    \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $ruleRepositoryInterface
    // ... any other dependencies
) {
    $this->ruleRepositoryInterface = $ruleRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Now, wherever you need it, you can load the `RuleInterface` and use that to get the discount amount:

```
$rule = $this->ruleRepositoryInterface->getById($ruleId);
echo $rule->getDiscountAmount();
```

Comment: thanks. but i recive an error when i add this code. Index->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory), Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Interceptor))

Comment: @AlinLupoiu Can you please post your full `__construct` method? It sounds like you may have a problem with the dependencies. Also, are you running in developer mode?

Comment: this not retrieve conditions